# Java collect() Stream with generic type

Tags: java, generics, collections, java-stream

Is there way to `collect()` generic items from a `stream` ?

This is what I want to do...

```
private <T extends Data> List<Response<T>> validateAndGetResponses(List<Response> responses, Class<T> clazz) {
        Supplier<List<Response<T>>> supplier = LinkedList::new;

        List<Response<T>> list = responses.stream().filter(
                response -> clazz.isInstance(getData(response))).collect(Collectors.toCollection(supplier));
        return list;

}
```

This doesn't work, I get

`no suitable method found for collect(....)`

Comment: Please post the full error message.  Even if you don't understand it, it will help us help you.

Comment: This compiles just fine. Could you post your imports?

Comment: I agree with @JeffreyBosboom. So far the code you wrote even compile fine. The only thing off is responses argument that should probably be List<Response<T>>.

Comment: @fabriziocucci - that indeed was the issue. Thanks !

Comment: And just as a side note: sometimes (not here obviously), a method returning something generic needs a type hint, meaning that you have to do  `foo. <ExpectedGenericType> someMethod(.... `  instead of  `foo.someMethod(.... `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the problem was I used a raw type `List<Response> responses` as an argument, though I really should of used a wildcard boundary, `List<Response<? extends Data>> responses`.

This is the complete method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private  <T extends Data> List<T> validateAndGetResponses(List<Response<? extends Data>> responses, Class<T> clazz) {
    return responses.stream().map(this::getData)
                             .filter(clazz::isInstance)
                             .map(r -> (T) r)
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Ok so now you are saying that you just want to return a List<T extends Data> instead of a List<Response<T extends Data>>. This is the only difference with my response and should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

So, if the purpose of the code is indeed filtering the Response objects based on the type parameter, a wild guess of the solution could be:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <T extends Data> List<Response<T>> validateAndGetResponses(List<Response<? extends Data>> responses, Class<T> clazz) {
    return responses.stream()
            .filter(response -> clazz.isInstance(getData(response)))
            .map(response -> (Response<T>) response)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
}
```

Comment: This makes me really wary. What if the `List` they are passing in is a `List<Response>`? You've just inadvertently caused heap pollution. They appear to be filtering based on a type check so this seems likely. OP needs to go and remove *all* [raw types](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/2891664) from their code.

Comment: My mistake, I'm sorry. what @Radiodef wrote is true. since i'm filtering based on type, not all my list is `Response<T>`. it's more of `List<Response<? extends Data>>` which brings me back to my original question...

Comment: It's possible that what you need is just like a `map(r -> (Response<T>) r)` in your stream but what you're doing is too vague to me to suggest a solution without knowing more about it. What will compile is not necessarily what is correct & provably safe here, especially if `Response` is mutable. Unless you just don't care about unsafe generic code, I guess, but I've seen code like this blow up too many times on here.

Comment: @Radiodef Response is immutable, in this case. so filtering by class and then immediately casting to the right type is my best option ?

Comment: @Radiodef made a good point indeed. I'm guessing too what you code is meant to do and just making the compiler happy could do more harm than good! :) But yes, if you are just filtering the responses based on the class literal you are passing then the casting is probably your only option.

Comment: Semantically it makes more sense to me to cast after you've done the type filter.

Comment: @Radiodef please look at my answer - if think it's the best option we can get.